# AJAX: Wordpress filters inside $html do not work as intended

Tags: php, functions, filters, jquery, ajax

I am sending HTML content through some AJAX magic and while everything is working as I wish, the output gives something along those lines in the page:

```
"http://permalink.comtitle"
```

It's as if all the html tags (< a> and < p> there) were discarded.

Here's the PHP part in functions.php where I give $html its value:

```
if ($query->have_posts()){ 
        while ($query->have_posts()){ 
            $query->the_post();
            $html = '<a href=\"' . the_permalink() . '\" style=\"text-decoration:none;color:#666666;font-weight:bold;\"><p class=\"actuLink\">' . the_title() . '</p></a>';
        }
    }
    echo $html;
```

jQuery part (I give only the part where I send the data to the target since everything else work as intended):

```
success:function(data){
                $('#actu_ajax').html(data);
            }
```

**Edit:** As a side note, if I remove the filters the html tags are back there. I am surely missing something easy to spot...

Comment: unrelated - you don't need to escape double quotes with \ in single-quoted text.

Comment: Yes, I noticed it shortly after solving the problem. It even creates some inconveniences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`the_permalink` and `the_title` (by default) *echo* their value, and therefore can't be used in assignment. Use [`get_permalink`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_permalink), and  [`the_title( '', '', false )`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title).

Comment: It did the trick, thanks a lot! So fast and awesome, I have to wait to validate your answer, kind sir.